# Static assert on interface of type defined using CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, crtp

I'm working on a library where client code can define certain types using [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp). I've extracted the problem into the following code:

```
template <typename T, typename X>
struct A
{   
    void test(X x)
    {
        return static_cast<T &>(*this).test(std::forward<X>(x));
    }
};

struct B: public A<B, int>
{
    void test(int x){};
};

int main(void)
{
    B b;
    b.test(5);
};
```

I want to have the compiler validate that client-defined types (`struct B` in the example code) provide the required interface. The above code with segfault if `test` is not defined on `B`. I wrote a type trait, `api_defines_test<T>` that can check if the `test` member function is defined. I realize now that this won't work: the trait is satisfied by the `test` member function in the base class, and this approach also requires me to know the concrete type of the user-defined classes which obviously isn't possible. I'm not asking how I can assert on types that are not yet defined, but is there some clever way to get a similar effect?

Comment: You say it’ll crash (invoke UB) will It invoke? I think it will just fail to compile when you try to call the function.

Comment: Please try answering the following questions, I think it will clear part of your design difficulties - "Why do you need derived `test` with same name as base `test()`? Which one do you want to be called from the outside?"

Comment: @Ben good point - this code compiles successfully and segfaults when run on my laptop with Apple clang version 13.0.0, but fails to compile with any compiler on godbolt, including supposedly the same compiler + version. Maybe that behaviour was backported and I don't have it locally. @vvv444 the idea behind it is to use static polymorphism to avoid the overhead of dynamic dispatch. The `test` member function in the base class will be called.

Comment: @ArthurM In your case, B::test() overrides A::test(), thus in main you call B::test directly. Try naming them separately. E.g. test and do_test()

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch your initial meaning. That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a `static_assert` in the `A::test` method where you have access to `T` (which is the user defined CRTP type). You can apply whatever type constraints you need at that point even though the CRTP type has not been defined yet -- that is a feature of CRTP.

The methods in `A` should have different names than their corresponding implementations in `B` as mentioned by @vvv444 in the comments. In the canonical CRTP pattern, `A` provides the interface and `B` the implementation.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template <typename T, typename X>
struct A {
    void test(X x) {
        static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::test_impl)>);
        return static_cast<T &>(*this).test_impl(std::forward<X>(x));
    }
};

struct B: public A<B, int> {
    void test_impl(int x){};
};

int main(void) {
    B b;
    b.test(5);
};
```

If you do not declare `B::test_impl`, the `static_assert` will trigger. Of course, in this case the assert is redundant because you will get a compilation error without the assert. This just demonstrates the ability to apply type constraints to the CRTP type in `A`.

### Output

```
src/p1.cpp:11:70: error: no member named
      'test_impl' in 'B'
        static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::test_impl)>);
                                                                  ~~~^
src/p1.cpp:22:7: note: in instantiation of
      member function 'A<B, int>::test' requested here
    b.test(5);
```

Comment: I would also suggest using concepts if c++20 is available